# Trouble with using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

So, what I am trying to do is iterate through an array of x values, and for each iteration, get the current text value of label "plabel" + x (the labels are all already created and named. I am relatively new to using reflection, but from what I've read the following should work:

```
PropertyInfo pI;
pI = this.GetType().GetProperty("plabel" + count + ".Text"); //count is the current iteration #
MessageBox.Show(pI.Name);
```

But this is throwing a runtime exception. Can somebody please show me the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What are the details of the runtime exception?

Comment: Yeah, a stack trace would be stellar.

Comment: "plabel1.Text" is obviously not a property... My guess would be that it is a path toward one and the property would be "Text", right?

Comment: object reference not set to an instance of an object. Which I believe implies that it couldn't find it?

Comment: The GetProperty is Case Sensitive. Also you have .Text inside it, which I presume is a property of the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//Gets the label (includes private fields)
FieldInfo fi = this.GetType().GetField("plabel" + count, 
                   BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance); 

Label label = fi.GetValue(this) as Label;

if (label != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(label.Text);
}
```

Comment: That's assuming plabel is truly a property... and not a field.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras plabel is the name of the label being used. I'm not sure, would that be a field or a property?

Comment: Two problems with the code: **1.** You need to cast to `Label` on the third line. **2.** You can simply output `label.Text`; there's no need to discover `Text` via reflection

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras - quite correct.  I've updated to a field to assume that the label was added in the winforms designer.

Comment: @w0lf - excellent points.  I must be out of it today.

Comment: @jaykreeler: If you wrote it: "Label plabel1;" it's a field. If you wrote it "Label plabel1 { get; set; }", it's a property. It's all in the get/set.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras I think RQDQ is right and it was the designer who wrote the declaration

Comment: FieldInfo.GetValue() only has 1 parameter, remove the null

Also make sure if these properties are private, that you call GetField("plabel"+count, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)